# setX and setY not working when trying to position images

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, javafx-2

I am having problems with positioning my images in my JavaFX program using setX and setY on the ImageView's for the images. I am not sure what is the problem? Appreciate any help given!
*Here's my code:*

```
        Image rocket2 = new Image("img/Rocket.png");
        ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(rocket2);
        iv1.setX(60);
        iv1.setY(44);

        Image rocket1 = new Image("img/Rocket.png");
        ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(rocket1);
        iv2.setX(5);
        iv2.setY(16);

        Image background = new Image("img/space.png");
        ImageView iv3 = new ImageView(background);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(iv3, iv2, iv1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Space stuff");
        primaryStage.show();
```

I suspect that something goes wrong because I have set a background image.
[img here on what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDraN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't place your items in a [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) if you want to explicitly define their layout positions (`setX` and `setY`).  A StackPane is a managed layout pane.  It will automatically set the location of items added to it (default is to center everything one on top of the other inside the StackPane).

Instead use a [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) or a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html), which are not managed layout panes and allow you to layout your content in the Pane however you wish.

To layout your content inside the Pane, you can use [`setLayoutX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) and [`setLayoutY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutY-double-) rather than setX and setY, though I guess setX and setY should also work (I've never used them before on ImageView).

Pavlo, already created an answer while I was typing this (so this answer is a duplicate), but I'll leave this as it adds a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `StackPane` with `Pane` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you however want for whatever reason to position a item in a StackPane you can use [setTranslateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-) and [setTranslateY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateY-double-). Theese methods set the x and y values AFTER the StackPane has done its layouting, so you will have a different starting position depending on the Alignment your StackPane uses for its children.

Comment: Awesome, This helped keep one node in the stackpane centered while another slightly ajar. So glad I didn't miss this answer!